# Change "example" with current selection based on setattr("example".outmesh)

Tags: python, maya

I told myself to never ask `common sense` or `novice` questions if I can look it up on the web and to resort to asking people as the last resort. This will probably be a fundamental question but please do enlighten me!

My code :

```
obj = pm.ls (selection=True,sn=True,o=True)       # get selection = obj 
shapes = pm.listRelatives(obj)                    # get obj shapeNode name
cpmNode = pm.createNode('closestPointOnMesh')     # create 
closestPointOnMesh Node
pm.setAttr(shapes+".outMesh",cpmNode + ".inMesh") # setattr selection 
shapeNode to cpmNode inMesh
```

Error :

```
# Can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

I don't understand how `pm.setAttr(shapes+".outMesh",cpmNode + ".inMesh")` is making into a list. Isn't it a command with strings now?

And by putting `shapes` into `pm.setAttr(shapes+".outMesh",cpmNode + ".inMesh")` is giving me errors where `.outmesh` is a string?

Is `pm.setAttr(shapes+".outMesh",cpmNode + ".inMesh")` a list then?

How should I make my current selection shapeNode to change `pCubeShape1` if given example (below):

```
pm.setAttr("pCubeShape1.outMesh",cpmNode + ".inMesh")
```

Comment: `shapes = pm.listRelatives(obj)` probably returns a list. And `[] + 'any_string'` gives me the same error you are having.

Comment: well i do know we cant do list and string together. What i dont understand is where the hell is the list coming from lol. From what i understand, ```shapes = pm.listRelatives(obj)``` should be a string. i am trying to insert this "string" into ```"pm.setAttr(shapes+".outMesh",cpmNode + ".inMesh")"``` where this is a list if i am nt wrong

Comment: maybe you try print type(shapes), type(cpmNode) so you figure out if objects are string or list.
You can use pdb module too for trying possibilities on running code.

Comment: While perhaps the suggestion by @warcholprzemo is great, print type(shapes) tells me that shapes is a list. Perhaps I should rephrase my question to get a straight route to what i want to achieve.



```cmds.connectAttr("polyShape.outMesh", cpmNode + ".inMesh") #replace polyShape with your shapeNode's name``` 



Code from 

```https://www.aganimator.com/tutorials/2016/3/1/cpointmesh-npointcurve```



How or what ways should i approach changing the shapeNode name with my current selection given that "polyShape.outMesh" is being unicoded?

Answer (score 0):

As you suspected, `cmds.listRelatives` returns a list, not a string. That's because a transform can contain multiple shapes.

Also you cannot use `setAttr` to connect the shape's outMesh to the utility's inMesh. Instead you need to use `connectAttr`.

Try this:

```
import pymel.core as pm

obj = pm.ls (selection=True,sn=True,o=True)
shapes = pm.listRelatives(obj, shapes=True, ni=True, type="mesh") # Use flags to narrow down the proper shape.
cpmNode = pm.createNode('closestPointOnMesh')
pm.connectAttr(shapes[0]+".outMesh",cpmNode + ".inMesh") # Use the first item in the shapes list.
```

Comment: Thank you @Green Cell. This is the solution I have been looking for! Looks like there's a difference between set and connect Attr. I will study more on it and most appreciated for the kind explaination! Pardon me for the limited knowledge i have atm XD

Comment: Think of `setAttr` as a one time operation, where `connectAttr` would be something that sticks and calculates during playback (a connection between the two nodes). Generally if it needs to be done in the connection editor then it's `connectAttr`